# Laravel: if someone know's the app generated key

Tags: laravel-5

What someone could do if they have access to the application key of a laravel project?

What could be done?

Comment: Decrypt anything you’ve used that key to encrypt.

Comment: @MartinBean so I only need to change that key and everything is fine?

Comment: Fine in that _you_ also won’t be able to decrypt your own data any more.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, they can decrypt and encrypt almost anything and your app will accept it as an input.

For example with your app key, someone can generate cookies that will log them in as any user of your app, without using any password.

If someone stole that key, best is to regenerate it as soon as possible.

However it'll render everything encrypted by your app invalid. So remember me token, cookies, and session will get invalidated and everyone will have to login again.

Also, if you use the Encrypter class in your app, remember that it'll not be able to decrypt successfully any previously encrypted thing anymore, so you'll have to migrate data by decrypting it using the old key, then re-encrypting it with the new one.

Also the most annoying part is that every password created with Hash:make will no longer be valid. But well, if the attacker has access to your APP key, he also has access to your DB credential, and so your full password database isn't safe anymore and you should force users to regenerate all of their passwords.

Comment: I'm happy I asked you guys BEFORE I publish the app. So there's no problem in changing the key. Thank you!